# About 100 error in Xcode, Undefined symbol. In my unity project

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I build and load my unity app on the app store. And now i make new release, project build successfully. But when i try to archive it in Xcode there are ~100 Undefined symbol errors.

I tried to change architectures but it does not help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line in YourProjet > Build Setting > Search paths > Framework Search Paths

```
$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)
```

and it will work

Comment: Thanks for answer, maybe it will be helpful for someone. Actually i stopped develop this project.